# AutoCompleteBox in wpf toolkit display items in "rhino.commom.DaataContract.ClassName" form

Tags: wpf, mvvm, wpftoolkit, autocompletebox

```
<WPFToolkit:AutoCompleteBox 
    x:Name="atbParentGroup"  
    IsTextCompletionEnabled="True" 
    FilterMode="ContainsOrdinal"
    ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.Data.ParentProductGroupList}"  
    SelectedItem="{Binding DataContext.Data.SelectedParentProductGroup}"
    ValueMemberPath="ParentGroupName"
    Text="{Binding ParentGroupName}"
    Width="120"
    HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
    Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Margin="5,5,0,0" />
```

Comment: <WPFToolkit:AutoCompleteBox x:Name="atbParentGroup"  IsTextCompletionEnabled="True" FilterMode="ContainsOrdinal"
                                        ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.Data.ParentProductGroupList}"

Comment: itemssource property i hav binded

Comment: And what exactly is your question here?

Comment: If you want to provide additional information you can always edit your own post to improve the question - no need to post these bits of information as comments.

Answer (score 0):

Now I got it. Ensure that the property `ParentGroupName` you have set as `ValueMemberPath` delivers a nice result - e.g. a string.
If that is not the case you can provide the full path to the property you want to display:

```
ValueMemberPath="ParentGroupName.FullName"
```

or something like that.

Another possibility would be to override the `.ToString()`-method of the `ParentGroupName` to return something readable.

Additionally make sure the `Text`-property does not conflict with the others, if in doubt, don't bind it at all. The `SelectedItem`-property will do its job.

Comment: public class ParentGroup
    {
       public global::System.Int32 ParentProductGroupID
        {
            get { return _parentProductGroupID; }
            set { _parentProductGroupID = value; }
        }
        private global::System.Int32 _parentProductGroupID;

        [DataMember]
        public global::System.String ParentGroupName
        {
            get { return _parentGroupName; }
            set { _parentGroupName = value; }
        }
        private global::System.String _parentGroupName;
    } .this is my class and in itemsSource i binding list of ProductGroug  Property

Comment: Then I assume "rhino.commom.DaataContract.ClassName" is actually the content of the `ParentGroupName`-property...

Comment: ProductGroupName is string type

Comment: DataContext.Data.ParentProductGroupList .it type of  List<ProductGroup>.

Comment: If you debug your application what are the contents of the `ParentGroupName`-property?

Comment: GroupName likes "steel","Sand" ...in string type

Comment: Selecteditems and ValueMember is working but the item that is display in "rhino.commom.DataContranct.ClassName" it is path of my class where i hav been created ProductGroup Class

Comment: See my edited answer. Short form: Remove the setting of the `Text`-property in your XAML.
(Please mark this answer as answered if it has helped you)